# Line up for golf!

Tags: code-golf, parsing, sorting

Alice, Bob, Carol, Dave, and Eve are going out for a nice game of golf and need your help to decide in what order they will play.

Your program will input some statements, which are defined as a condition, and then one or more optional logical boolean operators followed by another condition. (That's `[Condition]([Logical][Condition])*` in regexp notation.) A logical boolean operator is "and" or "or." You may chose either `and` or `or` to have higher precedence, as long as it is consistent.

A condition is a name, followed by the word "is," followed optionally by the word "not," followed by one of these:

- in front of
- behind
- n spaces in front of
- n spaces behind
- next to
- nth
- nth to last

An example of a valid condition is "Alice is not next to Bob".

Associativity is from left to right, except for "not," which only applies to a single statement. This means that "x or y and z or not a" means "((x or y) and z) or a," where x could be "Alice is 1st" or "Alice is behind Bob" or "Alice is not 2nd to last."

Your output must be the order in which the players line up, separated by commas, from front to back of the line.

Here's the full specification in regexp notation:

```
[Statement] = [FullCondition]([Logical][FullCondition])*
[FullCondition] = [Name] is [Condition]
[Condition] = (not)? (in front of|behind|[Number] space(s)? (in front of|behind)|next to|[Ordinal]|[Ordinal] to last)
[Logical] = and|or
[Number] = 1|2|3|4...
[Ordinal] = 1st|2nd|3rd|4th...
```

Standard methods of input and output. Input should be as a string, and output can be as a string or list.
And finally, here are some sample inputs and outputs.

```
Input:
The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.
Alice is 2nd.
Bob is in front of Alice.

Output:
Bob, Alice, Carol

Input:
The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.
Alice is 1 space in front of Bob. // remember to handle pluralization correctly!
Carol is 1st to last.

Output:
Alice, Bob, Carol

Input:
The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.
Alice is in front of Bob.

Output:
Alice, Bob, Carol
Carol, Alice, Bob // multiple outputs may be required

Input:
The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.
Alice is in front of Bob.
Bob is in front of Alice.

Output:
// nothing

Input:
The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.
Alice is not in front of Bob and Carol is not 2nd or Bob is 1st.

Output:
Carol, Bob, Alice
Bob, Alice, Carol
Bob, Carol, Alice
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes will win!

A great many thanks to @Doorknob for posting this in the Secret Santa's Sandbox. Again, thank you.

Comment: This was one I was going to take over but you really should repost it in sand box as it may need work

Comment: I worded it wrong. I looked at taking it over and never posted anything on it :P I instead posted a different one. But it may be finished.

Comment: Are lists a valid output format? So for example `{{Alice, Bob, Carol}, {Carol, Alice, Bob}}` for the third test case, and `{{Alice, Bob, Carol}}` for the second?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, I'll edit.

Comment: Commonly in mathematics, `and` is taken to have higher precedence than `or`. (`and` is multiplication in the boolean algebra, while `or` is sort of addition.) Can the solver choose which convention (this, or left-associativity) they'll consistently use?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes. Consistently.

Comment: This seems another challenge for Prolog!

Comment: Your regexp seems to allow statements like "Alice is next to Bob or behind Carol and Bob is 2nd to last or not 2 spaces in front of Carol" (note the omission of the subject's name in two of the four condition clauses). Is this intentional? And if so, does this example conflict with left-associativity, with which "Bob is 2nd to last" is supposed to be bound more tightly to "Alice is next to Bob or behind Carol" than to "not 2 spaces in front of Carol"? (And if so, more test cases please!)

Comment: @GregMartin `((((Alice is next to Bob) or [Alice is] behind Carol) and Bob is 2nd to last) or [Alice is] not 2 spaces in front of Carol)`. Left associativity is the rule here. This does not contradict the last test case because `(Alice is not in front of Bob) and [Alice is] Carol` does not make sense, which would make the entire parenthesis-enclosed version `((Alice is not in front of Bob) and (Carol is not 2nd)) or (Bob is 1st)`, and everything works out. Left-associativity is not conflicted, and this is intentional. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I truly don't see how your parsing of my example makes sense. How can the subject "Alice" be more tightly bound to "not 2 spaces in front of Carol" than "Bob", with all those nested parentheses in the way? I don't think either left-associativity or a common-sense reading supports that parsing. Perhaps, since you don't have any relevant test cases anyway, you can just change the spec to `[Statement] = [FullCondition]([Logical][FullCondition])*`.

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah, I see my mistake, sorry. But thank you for the new regexp, I think it makes more sense for this challenge. I will edit it in.

Comment: oh good, I thought maybe I was going crazy....

Comment: Can we assume something about the names? Are they always a subset of `{Alice, Bob, Carol, Dave, Eve}` or do we have to handle others?

Comment: @Pietu1998 Yes, it is okay.

Comment: @Arnauld This is not okay, but I do not expect it to be to hard to fix. Sorry.

Comment: Does `next to` equal `1 space behind` or also `1 space in front of`?

Comment: @Titus Yes, it does. `next to = ((1 space behind) or (1 space in front of))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>554</s> <s>499</s> ... 463 bytes

Takes input as an array of strings and returns an array of arrays of strings. Parsing rule: `and` has higher precedence than `or`.

Below is a slightly formatted version. The compact version is included in the snippet.

```js
([P,...C])=>
  [...Array(m=9349)]
  .map(_=>p[a=P.match(/[A-E]\w+/g).sort(_=>(k=k*2%m)&1)]?0:p[a]=a,p={},k=1)
  .filter(s=>
    s&&eval(
      C.join`and `.match(/.+?(or |and |$)/g)
      .map(s=>
        (
          c=s.match(/([A-E]\w+|\d|no|la|fr|be|x|p|or|an)/g),
          S=n=>`s.indexOf('${c[p+n]}')`,
          E=`]=='${c[0]}'`,
          c[p=1]=='no'?(p++,'!(s['):'(s['
        )+
        (
          (x=+c[p])&&p++,
          {
            la:'s.length-'+x+E,
            fr:F=S(1)+-1+E,
            be:B=S(1)+'+1'+E,
            x:F+'||s['+B,
            p:S(2)+(c[p+1]>'f'?-x:'+'+x)+E
          }[c[p]]||--x+E
        )+
        (c.pop()>'o'?')||':')&&')
      ).join``+1
    )
  )
```

#### How it works

**1. Initialization**

The input array is split into:

- `P` = first line, describing the players
- `C` = array containing all other lines

We first extract the names of all players from `P`:

```js
P.match(/[A-E]\w+/g)
```

We compute all permutations of the names, using several iterations of `sort()`:

```js
sort(_ => (k = k*2 % 9349) & 1)
```

The prime `9349` was (empirically) chosen in such a way that all permutations are guaranteed to be found, given enough iterations of the sort, for up to 5 players.

**2. Filtering**

The main part of the function consists of filtering these permutations to keep only the ones that match all conditions in `C`.

We join the different condition lines with `and` and split the resulting string on `or` and `and` to get an array of conditions.

Each condition is parsed to isolate the relevant tokens:

```
Token          | RegExp part
---------------+------------
Name of player | [A-E]\w+
Digit          | \d
'not'          | no
'last'         | la
'in front of'  | fr
'behind'       | be
'next to'      | x
'spaces'       | p
'or'           | or
'and'          | an
```

Each condition is translated into JS code:

```
Condition                     | JS code
------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
'X is Nth'                    | s[N - 1] == 'X'
'X is Nth to last'            | s[s.length - N] == 'X'
'X is in front of Y'          | s[s.indexOf('Y') - 1] == 'X'
'X is behind Y'               | s[s.indexOf('Y') + 1] == 'X'
'X is next to Y'              | s[s.indexOf('Y') - 1] == 'X' || s[s.indexOf('Y') + 1] == 'X'
'X is N spaces in front of Y' | s[s.indexOf('Y') - N] == 'X'
'X is N spaces behind Y'      | s[s.indexOf('Y') + N] == 'X'
```

Finally, all codes are joined with `||` and `&&` operators and the resulting string is `eval()`'d.

For example, below are the translations of the test cases as JS code:

```js
(s[1]=='Alice')&&(s[s.indexOf('Alice')-1]=='Bob')&&1
(s[s.indexOf('Bob')-1]=='Alice')&&(s[s.length-1]=='Carol')&&1
(s[s.indexOf('Bob')-1]=='Alice')&&1
(s[s.indexOf('Bob')-1]=='Alice')&&(s[s.indexOf('Alice')-1]=='Bob')&&1
!(s[s.indexOf('Bob')-1]=='Alice')&&!(s[1]=='Carol')||(s[0]=='Bob')&&1
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

([P,...C])=>[...Array(m=9349)].map(_=>p[a=P.match(/[A-E]\w+/g).sort(_=>(k=k*2%m)&1)]?0:p[a]=a,p={},k=1).filter(s=>s&&eval(C.join`and `.match(/.+?(or |and |$)/g).map(s=>(c=s.match(/([A-E]\w+|\d|no|la|fr|be|x|p|or|an)/g),S=n=>`s.indexOf('${c[p+n]}')`,E=`]=='${c[0]}'`,c[p=1]=='no'?(p++,'!(s['):'(s[')+((x=+c[p])&&p++,{la:'s.length-'+x+E,fr:F=S(1)+-1+E,be:B=S(1)+'+1'+E,x:F+'||s['+B,p:S(2)+(c[p+1]>'f'?-x:'+'+x)+E}[c[p]]||--x+E)+(c.pop()>'o'?')||':')&&')).join``+1))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  'The players are Alice, Bob and Carol.',
  'Alice is 2nd.',
  'Bob is in front of Alice.'
])));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  'The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.',
  'Alice is 1 space in front of Bob.',
  'Carol is 1st to last.'
])));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  'The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.',
  'Alice is in front of Bob.'
])));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  'The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.',
  'Alice is in front of Bob.',
  'Bob is in front of Alice.'
])));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  'The players are Alice, Bob, and Carol.',
  'Alice is not in front of Bob and Carol is not 2nd or Bob is 1st.'
])));
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>527</s> <s>524</s> 511 bytes

```python
import re,itertools as I
S=re.sub
p=re.findall(r"\w+(?=[,.])",input())
l=[]
try:
 while 1:
  c=[["not "*("not "in c)+S(" .+o (.+)",r" in[\1+1,\1-1]",S(" .+f","+1==",S(" .+d","-1==",S(r" .+(\d+).+",r"+1==\1",S(r" .+(\d+).+st",r"==len(p)-\1",S(r" .+(\d+).+f",r"+\1==",S(r" .+(\d+) .+d",r"-\1==",c[:-1]))))))),c][len(c)<7]for c in re.split("(or|and) ",input())]
  while c[1:]:c[:3]=["("+" ".join(c[:3])+")"]
  l+=[c[0]]
except:print([P for P in I.permutations(p)if eval("and ".join(l),dict(zip(P,range(len(p)))))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#ZVGxbhwhFOz3K55eBYFDJikirYKiJJW7k5yOpVizrI2FAbGcHUf59wt4c7IU08CbGWYej7N/zKlUKI776kpNKWwwb3A93KjixHa6HXI/rD4ucwik4PTMyFeluTAUuY/5VAmlQ1DaDLW8jAM83/vgQLYTWKU1xlQBP5B99xEsZTcEQbAERLBmUhB81JNkkk/yIA3ynV@RI5NKXeql1Yd/dekAmRZGBesOXTfJ/5mtdk6p4CLJ9PBesL7end6Z7mkFDztl9dj6ovvi1uhuaOmXz2ZNBWxrH/qwcvCVIEnlzxwXCm/jMW0W@1islqMZm98nozQSZAgoHpJvdh2jDCl2dWBKW31lzOB@WZfrmIuPlegj9MRjT7wW2ZXHU52rT3Fr7/MruKc5EGzpF9dA@eJtJb99Jkde5njnyD6Nvgw9n3/eO8hhfnGlfXxx8C146zh8T7ccutGPuaQghlcY/Ab9G1v6WlKskNYufNNdBB8b0PrsXEPkVsVf)

Outputs an array of valid permutations. Expects the names to only contain `A-Za-z0-9_` (`Alice` through `Eve` are obviously valid).

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, way too long (<s>790 744 725 697 678</s> 669 bytes)

```php
foreach(file(F)as$i=>$s)if($i){$g("#(.*)( and | or |\.)#U",$s,$w,2);foreach($w as $q){preg_match("#^(\w+)(.*?)(\w+)$#",$q[1],$m);$n=$u[-3+$p=($o=strpos)($u=$m[2],p)];$d.="!"[!$o($u,no)]."(".strtr(!$o($u,x)?A.($o($u,f)?$p?"==B-$n":"<B":($o($u,b)?$p?"==B+$n":">B":"==".preg_replace("#.*(\d).*#",($k=$o($u,a))?"$z-$1":"$1",$k?$u:$m[3]))):"(A-B)**2<2",[A=>$m[1],B=>$m[3]]).")$q[2]";}$d=!$x.="&"[!$x]."($d)";}else{($g=preg_match_all)("#(\w+)[.,]#",$s,$m);$z=count($y=$m[1]);}for(;$j++<10**$z;)if(count_chars($p="$j",3)==join(range(1,$i=$z))){for($c=$x;$i--;)$c=strtr($c,["."=>"","not"=>"",$y[$p[$i]-1]=>$i+1]);for(;eval("return$c;")&++$i<$z;)echo$y[$p[$i]-1],"
,"[$i<$z-1];}
```

takes input from file `F`, no trailing newline; `and` before `or`. Run with `-nr` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de7a0d4e2c576ff1252e7414dbf36bfb68753a7d).

**breakdown**

```php
foreach(file(F)as$i=>$s)if($i)              # loop through input lines
{
    $g("#(.*)( and | or |\.)#U",$s,$w,2);       # split statement to conditions
    foreach($w as $q)
    {
        preg_match("#^(\w+)(.*?)(\w+)$#",$q[1],$m); # 1. copy names to $m[1],$m[3]
        $n=$u[-3+$p=($o=strpos)($u=$m[2],p)];       # 2. remove names, 3. find N in "N spaces"
        $d.="!"[!$o($u,no)]."(".                    # 4. negate, 6. concatenate
            strtr(                                  # 5. translate condition:
            !$o($u,x)
            ?A.($o($u,f)?$p?"==B-$n":"<B"               # (N spaces) in front of
            :($o($u,b)?$p?"==B+$n":">B"                 # (N spaces) behind
            :"==".preg_replace("#.*(\d).*#",            # N-th
                ($k=$o($u,a))?"$z-$1":"$1"                  # ... (to last)
                ,$k?$u:$m[3])
            ))
            :"(A-B)**2<2"                               # next to
        ,[A=>$m[1],B=>$m[3]])
        .")$q[2]";
    }
    $d=!$x.="&"[!$x]."($d)";                    # concatenate statements, clear statement
}else                                           # first line: import names to $y, count to $z
{($g=preg_match_all)("#(\w+)[.,]#",$s,$m);$z=count($y=$m[1]);}
                                            # loop through combinations
for(;$j++<10**$z;)if(count_chars($p="$j",3)==join(range(1,$i=$z))){
    for($c=$x;$i--;)                            # remove dot and "not", replace names
        $c=strtr($c,["."=>"","not"=>"",$y[$p[$i]-1]=>$i+1]);
                                                # all conditions met? print combination!
    for(;eval("return$c;")&++$i<$z;)echo$y[$p[$i]-1],"\n,"[$i<$z-1];
}
```